# How can I modify each Content inside of Curly brackets of CustomView separately in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

How can I modify each Content inside of Curly brackets of CustomView separately, in down code I am modifying the offset of content which is working fine, but it apply's to all Content's of CustomView and then takes the next Index of EachFor and do the same. Which is correct and doing its Job!

**My Goal in this Question is finding a way to tell the CustomView to modify One by One, Not all together!**

*PS: my goal of using CustomView was/is making me free to modify code in ContentView. I want just load my contents inside of Curly brackets of CustomView, and all the modifying happens inside of CustomView. and this CustomView could take any View/Content.*

***my Goal output Image:***

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            
            CustomView {
                Text("Hello, world! 1")
                Text("Hello, world! 2")
                Text("Hello, world! 3")
                Text("Hello, world! 4")
                Text("Hello, world! 5")
            }
        }
    }
    
struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
        
        var inPutView: () -> Content
        
        init(@ViewBuilder inputView: @escaping () -> Content) {
            self.inPutView = inputView
        }
        
        var body: some View
        {
            VStack {
                
                ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                    inPutView().offset(x: CGFloat(index*20))
                }
                
            }
        }
 }
```

***output of this code:***

[image]

**update:**

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomView {
            Text("Hello")
            Image(systemName: "folder")
            Text("Omid")
            Image(systemName: "star")
            Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .center)
            HStack { Image(systemName: "person"); Image(systemName: "1.circle").foregroundColor(Color.green) }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    
    var inPutView: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder inputView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.inPutView = inputView
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack {
            
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                inPutView().offset(x: CGFloat(index*20))
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here seems to me is a possible approach to solve such kind of tasks. At least a way to move...

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomView(5) {
            Text("Hello, world! \($0 + 1)")
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    private var count: Int
    var inPutView: (Int) -> Content
    
    init(_ count: Int = 1, @ViewBuilder inputView: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.count = count
        self.inPutView = inputView
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach((0..<count).indices, id: \.self) { index in
                inPutView(index).offset(x: CGFloat(index*20))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my goal of using CustomView was/is making me free to modify code in ContentView. I want just load my contents inside of Curly brackets of CustomView, and all the modifying happens inside of CustomView. and this CustomView could take any View/Content. please look an my update in code.